# Understanding session$onFlush in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have problems understanding the `onFlush` function in shiny on when registered function get exactly called.

Looking at its reference: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.6.0/topics/onFlush it suggest that registered functions will be triggered before the observers and render functions get recalculated.

Since it states the following:

> onFlush registers a function that will be called before Shiny flushes the reactive system.

What I understand as a *flush* is the re-computation of all the observers and render functions. This idea is supported by one of their [official articles](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html), stating:

> Once all the descendants are invalidated, a *flush* occurs. When this happens, all invalidated observers re-execute.

---

Thus when I run the following minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( actionButton("invalidate", "invalidate")  )
    
server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  session$onFlush( function() message("Start flush"), once = FALSE)
  session$onFlushed( function() message("End flush"), once = FALSE )
  
  observe({
     Sys.sleep(3) # Long computation  
     input$invalidate
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expect to see first the message: `Start flush` then a 3 second pause and then the message `End flush`.

In reality however, the `start flush` is only executed after the `observe` was executed, while I would have thought that this would get executed before the `observe`.

At first, I thought this was a bug, however I then found this official shiny example:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/127-async-flush/app.R
and learned that this order of execution is actually the intended behavior.

So now I am actually not sure how I need to interpret the `onFlush` function or what the *flush* is in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to interpret the `onFlush` function in a similar way `on.exit` is working in a non-reactive context. We can read both as "before flush" and "before exit", since they both execute functions before a flush occurs or before a functions exits. This is the reason why the `start flush` message is shown after the `observe` was executed.

I changed the app a little to make the example easier to follow (at least I hope it helps):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( actionButton("invalidate", "invalidate")  )

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  session$onFlush( function() message("Start flush"), once = FALSE)
  session$onFlushed( function() message("End flush"), once = FALSE )
  
  observeEvent(input$invalidate, {
    print(input$invalidate)
    Sys.sleep(3) # Long computation    
  }, 
  ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think the following is happening when we click on the `actionButton`;

1. the value of `input$invalidate` changes from `0` to `1`
2. change of `input$invalidate` triggers `observeEvent`
3. the `observeEvent` is executed (`print` and `Sys.sleep`)
4. the `observeEvent` is invalidated
5. `onFlush` prints `"Start flush"`
6. a flush occurs
7. `onFlushed` print `"End flush"`
8. The `observeEvent` is re-executed and now listens to the new value of `input$invalidate`

There is almost no time difference between before and after the flush. That is the reason both messages are printed directly after each other.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I can follow your answer but then it is not clear to me what a "flush" means. As I stated in my original answer. I find evidence that the "flush" is the actual execution of the reactive system. While your answer seems to suggest that it is something that happens after the execution. I am not really convinced by that. This is also what the Joe Cheng explains here in this vignette: https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html#the-flush-cycle (disregard the asyn-part) 

So what is the flush exactly? Thanks for thinking along :)